# Is it possible to "detach" TS 2008 remote app?

Tags: windows, terminal-server

Is it possible to close an open TS 2008 remote app but keep it running in the background? With a possibility to reconnect?

Answer (score 1):

Use the tsdiscon command, see:

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/321705

For lusers you might be able to come up with some clever scripting to do this. It's not trivial as you need the session id.

JR

Comment: great idea, thanks. but works only for apps who has a console like total commander or powershell. still wondering how to close i.e. firefox from the client side keeping it running.

Answer (score 0):

To the best of my knowledge, at that point you're past terminal sessions, and into the realms of application virtualization, but wiser minds than mine may know of a middle ground.

Answer (score 0):

By default your users will reconnect to the same session they were before on. 
Try in the TS settings to increase disconnect time, maybe they are trying to connect after disconnect timeout is reached, any they are opening then new session.